# Sharepoint 2013 Images in Image List vs on file system

Tags: image, caching, model-view-controller, sharepoint, blob

We want to manage images for MVC web site

I want to know performance wise, what is better choice

1. we source images from sharepoint (public site) and take advantage of managing images in list, Image Renditions and blob cache
2. we manage images on file system for our mvc web site.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are static, and are not maintained by SharePoint users, then it will be faster to use local disk based files on your web servers.

disk -> MVC app -> end user

vs.

disk -> SQL -> SharePoint Servers -> (maybe SharePoint server cach) -> MVC app -> end user

Comment: what do you think sp cach > mvc > end user this will be faster as well, this is what making me confused. thanks

Comment: In the end, the answer is "it depends" and you need to test it. If the SharePoint farm has a caching load balancer, then that could be very fast.